# gzip a folder in mac for iphone usage

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, macos, gzip

Is it possible to gzip a folder with 50 files and extract it in iPhone ?

Comment: This question might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take a look at this: http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/
I used it and I like it, really simple to extract any file as data from zip archive, if you need to extract it then you can just obtain documents folder path (writable location) and save all the files from archive in that location.

Answer (score 1):

For unzip, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412982/iphone-unzip). iTunes 9.2 and new iOS device allow user to add files to an app's document folder, take a look at the ""Application supports iTunes file sharing" attribute in the app .plist.