# is there any working Unzip code for iphone?

Tags: iphone

this is the link for unzip (no links please)

Comment: either your english is so bad or your question is so unclear. I don't get it

Comment: sorry i was drinking beer while writing :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Unzip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412982/iphone-unzip)

Comment: i am sorry plz dont ban me give me last chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want the code to unzip a file you have downloaded?

See [iPhone Unzip code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412982)