# Zip and UnZip a file programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, zip, ziparchive-objectivec

How can we zip and unzip a file through coding?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a zip file by using Objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286496/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-by-using-objective-c)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412982/iphone-unzip-code) SO questions.

And here is a library [ziparchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/)

> ziparchive An Objective C class for
>   zip/unzip on iPhone and Mac OSX

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [ZipKit](https://github.com/kolpanic/ZipKit) also.

> ZipKit is an Objective-C framework for reading and writing Zip archives in Mac OS X and iOS apps, it supports:
>
> - the standard PKZip format
> - files larger than 4GB in size using PKZip's zip64 extensions
> - optionally, resource forks in a manner compatible with Mac OS X's Archive Utility (in the > Mac OS X targets only)
> - clean interruption, so archiving can be cancelled by the invoking object (e.g., a NSOperation or NSThread).

Comment: This repo has now been deleted