# How do I zip files programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zip and UnZip a file programmatically in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029917/zip-and-unzip-a-file-programmatically-in-iphone)

I want to zip images and audio programmatically in my app.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please refer answer of [Question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029917/zip-and-unzip-a-file-programmatically-in-iphone) and [Question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286496/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-by-using-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

Try [**ZipKit**](https://github.com/kolpanic/ZipKit). Put this as part of your build and then

`#import <ZipKit/ZipKit.h>`

After this you are good to go.

Comment: will the ZipArchive class work for ios 3.1.3

Comment: dont know and dont care. Neither should you. iOS is currently in iOS6.x. Generally most developers dont support more than 2 versions. So I suggest you stop worrying about such old versions and check it works in the latest of the latest ones. unless you have a strong reason to do so...

Comment: The link is broken as well probably removed long time ago.

Comment: @Gorky updated the zip file repo link