# Not Unzipping Files > 2 GB iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unzip, large-files

I'm Using [SSZipArchieve](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive/issues/81) to Unzip a file over *2GB (2.69 GB Precisely)*.

I'hv implemented the following method to unzip File

```
(BOOL)unzipFileAtPath:(NSString *)path toDestination:(NSString *)destination delegate:(id)delegate;

[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:sourcePath toDestination:destinationPath delegate:self];
```

Which returns NO.

I Debugged the problem & found out that I Get the `UNZ_BADZIPFILE` in function `unzOpenInternal()`. I cross checked with the zip file & its unzipping correctly on my Desktop.

I'm stuck, Please let me know how do I get this working. A quick response will be highly valuable & appreciable

Comment: please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029917/zip-and-unzip-a-file-programmatically-in-iphone

Comment: I've had success with [ZipKit](https://github.com/kolpanic/ZipKit) on files over 2GB (but under 4GB).

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks,I checked it out but I need support for iOS 5.0 also.