# how to access the content within the zip file in iphone

Tags: iphone, zip

I have a zip file. In that zip file I have some ppt presentation.

I want to show that ppt presentation in my `UIWebView`.

I cannot extract and show ppt files there directly .

How do I access the ppt inside the zip in objective c?

Comment: look at the answer by john on this page possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103509/download-and-open-zip-folder-path-in-iphone

Comment: and also from sam jophess on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412982/iphone-unzip-code

Answer (score 1):

This isnt easy.  You might want to consider doing this another way.  For example you could put the file unzipped on a server and open the link in a webview.

However, if you really want to do it this way there is 2 step.

**1. Unzip the file.**

You want end up with `NSData`.  Read though some of the links [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412982/iphone-unzip-code) in the comments.  You will need to use a 3rd party library to achieve this.

**2. Load the data in to a `UIWebView`.**

Write the NSData to the temp directory then point the `UIWebView` at it.

```
NSString *path = // .. Get a location in the NSTemporaryDirectory
if ([pptData writeToFile:path atomically:YES]) 
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview loadRequest:request]; 
}
```