# Regarding retriving downloaded data in iPhone

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Here in my application i download the zip file that contains few images, now i have to unzip that zip file and have to retrive that images to display, i am using zip archive to identify zipfile downloaded and to unzip the downloaded zip file, please help to retrieve the images in the unzipped file.

Thanks
GuruPrasad R Gujjar.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412982/iphone-unzip-code) is the discussion for the problem you are asking. This shall help you.