# How unzip .gz file and zip file with extension .gz

Tags: ios, objective-c, gzip, gunzip

I am getting database "swx.sqlite.gz" from server now i need to uncompress it to swx.sqlite and play with this in application.

After that when i need to send the database file then i need to compress it to swx.sqlite.gz and sent back to server.

I have searched a lot but i didn't find and lib or files for .gz extension. Like ZipArchive, SSZipArchive are working with only .zip extension.

Comment: From the command line use `gzip -d` or `gunzip`. I think the correct library is zlib.

Comment: may be it is duplicate but i dint find my desire solution out there.

Comment: The accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone states that `NSURLRequest` handles gzip encoded payloads transparently. That would take care of download part. It may just be a question of ensuring that the right HTTP headers are in place when the server sends out the data. Have you verified if that works?

Comment: For Unzip file http://stackoverflow.com/a/1284210/1312051 this worked for me :)